# How to load image in the source code directory to webview in React Native Android

Tags: react-native

When I try to load image from network to webview like below works fine.

```
<WebView source={{ html: "<img src='abc.com/assets/img/logo.png'/><h1>Hello</h1>" }} />
```

But I am unable to load image from the source code directory to Webview. I am tried with the following code for that.

```
<WebView source={{ html: "<img src={require('./images/google_signin.png')} /><h1>Hello</h1>" }} />
```

If anyone knows how to load image from source code directory, please tell me.

Comment: local assets might not be accessible from webview. You can convert image into base64 and use it in html.

Comment: as @SagarKhatri mentioned, local assets are not accessible by the webview (apart from the source itself). There is/was a discussion on github regarding that exact issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505

Comment: @Kumar Discussion seems more on html page loading from local folder rather loading media asset in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Insert
       `allowFileAccess={true}`
       to your webview:

```
    <WebView
     allowFileAccess={true}
    source={{"<img src=\"" +"file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/mypicture.PNG" + "\" alt=\"\" style=\"width: 100%; max-width: 1061px;margin-bottom:5px;\" />}}
    style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
```

[AllowFileAccess](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/webview.md#allowFileAccess): Its boolean that sets whether the WebView has access to the file system. That will help your application access the file system from external storage.

Comment: Please provide explanation on your answer, how does it solve OP problem.?

Comment: what is the OP problem?

Comment: OP(Original poster)...Just add some explanation of your answer.It appeared in low quality post.

Comment: I'm so sorry. I can't explain why those codes work for me. But it really worked. And I share it with people who are in trouble like me.

Comment: you must be having some idea on what your code does. What allowFileAccess does?.where the code needs to be added?. something like that. Stackoverflow recommends answer with good code and explanation. It also helps future readers.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/master/docs/webview.md#allowFileAccess
allowFileAccess
Boolean that sets whether the WebView has access to the file system.
That will help your application access the file system from external storage.